# How to make loop not to continue until an event happens?

Tags: javascript, events, async-await

I am writing a function of a game:

```
function Game(){
    while(true){

        ***

        for(var i = 0; i < level; i++){
            var color;
            $(".btn").on("click", function(event) {
                ButtonClickResponse(this.id);
                color = this.id;
            });
            if(colorsOrder[i] != color){
                GameOver();
                return;
            }
        }

        ***

    }
    
}
```

the "if statement" in the loop of function runs and increments "i" immediately many times when loop is started and doesnt wait for an above event to finish.

I searched for solving with "async await" and "promise" in google and stackoverflow, but didn't really understand how it worked so couldn't implemet it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, although I didn't test it and you do things not in javascript way

```
async function Game() {
  while (true) {
    var level = 1;
    $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
    var colorsOrder = [];
    var randColor = GenerateRandomSquareColor();
    colorsOrder.push(randColor);
    ButtonClickResponse(randColor);

    for (var i = 0; i < level; i++) {
      var color;

      // await for the click event
      const event = await waitForClick($(".btn"));
      // do stuff with the result
      ButtonClickResponse(event.target.id);
      color = event.target.id;

      if (colorsOrder[i] != color) {
        GameOver();
        return;
      }

      level++;
    }
  }
}

function waitForClick(element) {
  // create new promise
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const handler = function (event) {
      // when button is clicked remove listener
      element.off("click", handler);
      // and resolve the promise
      resolve(event);
    };
    // listen for click
    element.on("click", handler);
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying not in js way? And can you please explain what does your wait for click function mean?

Comment: with your function return, event.id in the loop returns to undefined :-|

Comment: `while (true)` loop is hardly ever used. Usually, you should rely on events. I updated the answer, try using `event.target.id` instead of `event.id`

Comment: I generally agree with @3kShoter 's answer. But a couple more tips:
Don't use while(true) in JS. Use requestAnimationFrame instead. Also ditch var alltogether for const and let.

Comment: @GeriDremák How is `requestAnimationFrame` if OP isn't rendering anything?

Comment: requestAnimationFrame will work until the return isnt done?

Comment: Just use it, it won't clog your main thread like a while loop. (it is run when the actual browser window is getting redrawn and/or when some small amount of time passes)

It is usually ran maximum 60 times per second. I actually screwed up the original reply, I meant I agree with @Konrad

Comment: @GeriDremák `requestAnimationFrame` is bound to the screen refresh rate. On 60hz monitors it will run 60 times a second for example. I don't see how `requestAnimationFrame` would be better here when op still needs to await for the vent. Now with `await` the `while (loop)` won't clog the main thread anyway

Comment: Oh with await you are right. Sorry. 